# Assigning eigenkets to particular eigenspace depending on eigenvalues of system inside a module

Tags: physics, assignment, eigenvalues

I am writing a module, in which the Observable and State is given, so I need to write a function/module QuantumMeasurement, that will return a state of the quantum system resulting from the measurement. There are various inputs, so I need to write this function in a way, that will consider the system with different eigenvalues, let's say it can be `{1,1,2,2}` or `{1,2,3,4}`. Therefore the system will be divided in different number of eigenspaces, where each of them will consist of particular number of eigenkets.

So I need some kind of list of those eigenspaces, where each eigenket will be linked to correlated eigenvalue. Suppose eigenkets are:

```
{
 {{I/2,1/2,0,1/Sqrt[2]}},
 {{-(1/2),-(I/2),1/Sqrt[2],0}},
 {{-(I/2),-(1/2),0,1/Sqrt[2]}},
 {{1/2,I/2,1/Sqrt[2],0}}}
}
```

and eigenvalues are

```
{1,1,2,2}
```

Therefore it will be two eigenspaces, each of them consisting of two eigenkets[1,2] for the first eigenspace, and eigenkets[3,4] for the second eigenspace. How to assign those eigenkets to correllated eigenspace in order to use call this list later in the code?

That's what I have so far

```
Qmeasurement[x_, y_] := 
Module[
        {eikets = {}},
        {eigenvalues, eigenkets} = Eigensystem[G];
        For[j = 1, j <= Length[eigenkets], j++,
        ortho = Orthogonalize[{eigenkets[[j]]}
        ]
      ]
```

This is kind of preparation, where I am make the kets orthogonal in order to use them later on. I was thinking to use PositionIndex for my problem, but I am not sure how to properly assign it. Please post any suggestions, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your function takes `x,y` as arguments, but does not show how one gets `G` from `x,y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to group the eigenkets into orthogonal eigenspaces is like this:

```
eigenspaces = Table[
    Pick[eigenkets, Thread[eigenvalues == λ]], 
        {λ, Union[eigenvalues]}]
```

In the above, we are using `Union` to find the unique eigenvalues, and `Pick` to find all of the eigenkets whose position in the list is the same as the position of the eigenvalues.

There are several ways to make our `eigenspaces` orthonormal.  Here is one way.

```
orthospaces = Orthogonalize /@ eigenspaces
```

Another way is to use `Orthogonalize[ Pick[ ... ]]`  in the `Table` command.

Before writing the quantum measurement function it would be good to do some sample measurement calculations step-by-step.  After you calculate all the possible measurement results, the probabilities of each and the resulting states, you will have a better idea what the function must do.  And, you will already have some sample calcs to check the function against.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice solution!